# How to compute the product of the Unicode codes of all letters in a string with a for-loop?

Tags: scala, for-loop

I came up with this solution but it uses a var:

```
var prod = 1
for (i <- "Hello"){ prod *= i.toInt }; println(prod)
```

What would be your approach to this problem if you had to use a for-loop?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `for` in Scala is not necessarily a "loop": it's actually more general than that.

Comment: Just FYI, this is Exercise 6 on p.26 of "Scala for the Impatient".

Answer (score 4):

You don't use for comprehensions for that. Yes, for loops -- which are imperative constructs -- can be used, but you *will* be using vars in that case.

Explanation: a for comprehension is something that transforms an `M[A]` into an `M[B]`. For a `String`, `M` will be a `Seq` (or, perhaps, an `IndexedSeq`), and a `Seq` isn't an `Int`, nor is an `Int` parameterized.

For this kind of task you should use `foldLeft` or `foldRight` instead. These constructs can transform an `M[A]` into something else altogether. See also [the essence of the iterator pattern](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html), which provides a more general solution (and, whenever you read "general", think "more setup required").

Of course, the easy way is `"Hello".product.toInt`.

Comment: I know, but imagine you had to use a for-loop... Is the solution in my question above as good as it gets?

Comment: @Daniel `"Hello".product.toInt` overflows.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet All real world uses of multiplying char values I know of depend on overflow wrap-around.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BigInt` because `Int` will overflow.

```
"Hello" map (i => BigInt(i)) product
```

Or if you insist on for-loop, how about this :)

```
object Product { 
  def unapply[T: Numeric](xs: Seq[T]) = Some(xs.product) 
}

val Product(prod) = for(i <- "Hello") yield BigInt(i)

// prod: scala.math.BigInt = 9415087488
```

Comment: Nice use of `unapply`, this is one of the really cool things about Scala.

Comment: Well really it's a very stupid way to do something very simple; but it does show off a good range of Scala's features: first-class objects, extractors, context bounds, Options, pattern matching, for-comprehenions, and case classes... phew!

Answer (score 2):

The shortest correct solution seems to be:

```
"Hello".map(BigInt(_)).product
```

which gives the value expected in the book

```
9415087488
```

Comment: The 2011 edition of *Scala For The Impatient* expects 825152896, which is the overflowed Int value.  Might be why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1L)(_ * _)
```

Alternatively:

```
(1L /: "Hello")(_ * _)
```

Comment: Because @user1243091 explicitly asked how it could be done using a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually method `product`:

```
scala> "Hello".map(_.toInt).product
res0: Int = 825152896
```

If you really want the `for` keyword in your solution, you could do this:

```
scala> (for(c <- "Hello") yield c.toInt).product
res1: Int = 825152896
```

That technically has a for loop, but it's really just syntactic sugar for the previous thing that uses `map`.

Comment: In this case I actually would consider it 'syntactical salt'

Comment: @Jens Ha, yeah, I actually thought the same thing.  This is definitely below the threshold of where the for-comprehension makes things more readable.  But it *does* have a for-loop, as requested (and without sacrificing immutability.) :-)

Comment: @dhg This solution overflows too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Hello".map( _.toInt).reduce(_ * _)
```

or

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1)(_ * _)
```

Inspired by Jean-Philippe Pellet solution which causes a

```
type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: Char
```

At least in my Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use a for loop and want the for loop to actually do the work, I think your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Page 20 of the book, the Note callout mentions that you can wrap generators of a for loop inside braces.

So this:

```
{ for(i <- "hello") yield BigInt(i) }
```

Returns:

```
Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

Which you could call product on:

```
 { for(i <- "hello") yield BigInt(i) }.product

 // returns:  scala.math.BigInt = 13599570816
```

Hope that helps.