# Can someone explain this Scala map function to calculate the product of a string's unicode

Tags: scala

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519403/how-to-compute-the-product-of-the-unicode-codes-of-all-letters-in-a-string-with) solution for calculating the product of a string's unicode code points.

One of the answers includes this snippet:

```
"Hello" map (i => BigInt(i)) product
```

I had no idea this would compile. Can someone explain to me how this works? Why does it work with the whitespaces?

Comment: Because whitespace is the same as a method call in Scala.

Comment: Scala has lots of white space syntax that compiles as correct code. It is to improve redability of the code and be less verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line can be read as

```
{val string = "Hello"

 val charList = string.map(i=>BigInt(i))

 charList.product}
```

which returns the product as the result of the block of code

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to omit `.` for method calls. In Scala, `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo bar`. And `foo.bar(baz)` is the same as `foo bar baz`.

This style is not often used, and usually discouraged for all but the simplest code. This line overall is equivalent to:

```
"Hello".map(i => BigInt(i)).product
```

Comment: That's not what [point free is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming). That's infix and postfix notation.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new. Edited to remove the part calling it point free.